# How to extract positive numbers from one array and move them to another in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am probably doing it all wrong but I have an array of numbers and I would like to extract positive numbers from that array and put them into a separate array. I would potentially want to do the same with negative numbers.

Here's what I've tried (the code is wrong but I am stuck here at the moment):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};
 
 int [] arrayPositive = Arrays.copyOf(array, 13);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayPositive.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
          System.out.println("" + i);
      }
    }
```

Any feedback would be more than welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think with ```if( i > 0)``` you meant ```if(array[i] > 0)``` and ```System.out.println("" + array[i]);``` instead of only printing the counting variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};
        int l = array.length;
        int[] arrayPositive = new int[l];
        int[] arrayNegative = new int[l];
        int i,j,k;
        i=j=k=0;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++){
            if (array[i] > 0) {
                arrayPositive[j]=array[i];
                ++j;
            }
            else if(array[i] < 0){
                arrayNegative[k]=array[i];
                ++k;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++){
            System.out.println(arrayPositive[i]+"\t" + arrayNegative[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract positive numbers, your if should check whether each array element is greater than 0, like in the following code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayPositive.length; ++i) {
      if (arrayPositive[i] > 0) {
          System.out.println("" + arrayPositive[i]);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  int[] array = {12, 23, -22, 0, 43, 545, -4, -55, 43, 12, 0, -999, -87};
  
  int [] arrayPositive = new int[array.length];
 
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] > 0) {
          System.out.println(""+array[i] );
          arrayPositive[i]=array[i];
      }
    }
 
}
```